# Get linkedin connections ios

Tags: ios

Hii i'm trying to get linkedin connection. i have see some same questions but did not find any relevant solution. please help me how can i find connection using latest SDK and which permission i need for connections.
i have used argument as

```
#define LinkedInApiUrl @"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,headline,first-name,last-name)"


- (void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken
{
    [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json",LinkedInApiUrl,accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result)  {
        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);
        [self linkedinAuthenticationResponse:result error:nil];
    }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
                 [self linkedinAuthenticationResponse:nil error:error];
             }];
}

- (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)client
{
    LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication
                                           applicationWithRedirectURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"https://www.something.com"]

                                           clientId:LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID
                                           clientSecret:LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET
                                           state:@"someState"
                                           grantedAccess:@[ LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION,LISDK_RW_COMPANY_ADMIN_PERMISSION,LISDK_W_SHARE_PERMISSION ]];
    return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application presentingViewController:self];
}
```